# Custom path animation using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, animation

I've created this android app that sends onTouchEvents points to a web server, and I have a page which gets the motion points JSON data via Ajax like so:

```
{"data":[
{"x":224.28035,"y":235.4906},
{"x":263.32916,"y":219.45718},
{"x":293.3667,"y":215.44885},.....]}
```

Now I want to use this data and animate a div on the screen with smooth path animation, similar to flash path animation, is there a plugin that solves this issue?

PS: http://weepy.github.com/jquery.path/ does not seem to have a custom path animation, or I may be missing something.

Thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully this is the one you're searching for: jQuery plugin [crSpline](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/crSpline)

You can see its demo in [here](http://ijin.net/crSpline/demo.html).

Answer (score 4):

**### pathAnimator**

Ultra-lightweight, high performance with a nice range of settings.

### Example:

```
var path         = "M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"; // an SVG path
    pathAnimator = new PathAnimator( path ),   // initiate a new pathAnimator object
    speed        = 6, // seconds that will take going through the whole path
    reverse      = false,  // go back or forward along the path
    startOffset  = 0,   // between 0% to 100%
    easing = function(t){ t*(2-t) };  // optional easing function


pathAnimator.start(speed, step, reverse, startOffset, finish, easing);

function step( point, angle ){
    // do something every "frame" with: point.x, point.y & angle
}

function finish(){
    // do something when animation is done
}
```

Comment: pathAnimator looks cool but the demo seems to have a serious error: 
Argument 1 of SVGPathElement.getPointAtLength is not a finite floating-point value. 
@ js/pathAnimator.js: line 68

Comment: it works perfect for me on all supported browsers..Tested on IE9+, FF and Chrome. what is this `SVGPathElement` thing you are referring to?

Comment: Strange! When I copy>paste the code from the Github page (https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator/blob/master/README.md) without changing anything, Firefox generates the floating-point error. Chrome does not generate this error, but it still fails to traverse the path.

The full demo (in the zip file) IS working, so perhaps I should try and strip that down to the bare essentials. (the demo is a bit bloated, making the exact workings unclear).

Comment: so maybe you did something wrong..? I must see what you did in order to understand it. And the demo is not bloated, it's super easy basic JS, and it's obvious only the first 46 lines of code on the `main.js` file are the core of how to use pathAnimator, and everything else is just things which are specific for the demo.

Comment: By bloated I mean there's a lot of interface stuff going on, which makes it harder to get the pure animation code. The animation itself is very cool indeed! I'm glad someone took the trouble to make this, I'm sure I can find the error.
I have created a JSFiddle with the github example: http://jsfiddle.net/6nnRW/1/

Comment: you forgot to do this: `easing = function(t){ return t*(2-t) };` so basically you didn't return any value from the easing function, so the code was going mental, not understanding what to do.

Comment: @LuisSiquot - Thanks, fixed!